# Symfony Trouble logging in user to database, server crashing

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm trying to set up a Symfony install locally and followed this tutorial to create my User Controller

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#security-crete-user-entity

I manually edded the user to the mysql database and did not encode the password ( I didn't want to bother with a login form right now).

Here are my security settings:

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
          algorithm: bycrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        in_memory:~
        user:
          entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
            property: username
```

That is not all of them, but the relevant parts for this post. So when I try to log someone in, my symfony server crashes. I would understand if I can't login, but I should just get an error message, not crash the server. So I figure something is wrong with my controller or something else. Could this be related to the fact that the user password has not been encoded?

Comment: What are the logs saying? :)

Comment: didn't know there were logs, let me look into that :)

Comment: depending on your symfony version and your used environment you may  find the application logs either under `app/logs` or `var/logs`

Comment: ok well the logs helped, it got me one step closer to solving this. Matko if you put that in an answer I can mark this answered. It seems I am missing  UserRepository.php. Now that I know about the logs, I can keep checking them until I get this fixed!

Comment: Indeed the logs helped. Now the server is not crashing but I'm getting invalid credentials, which is to be expected

Comment: I am glad I could help you. But, it seems to me it is little silly that I put in the answer "Check the logs, man!" :)

Comment: yeah but it helped!